# How to fix "403"/"503" error in Scrapy Splash on Docker

Tags: scrapy, docker-compose, splash-screen, scrapyd

When I run my scrapy/splash config on Docker, scrapy **can't connect to Splash, due to 403/503 error** appears.

This is my docker-compose file :

```
  scraper:
    build:
      context: ./my_scraper
    image: "my_scraper"
    ports:
      - 6800:6800
    depends_on:
      - splash
  splash:
    image: "scrapinghub/splash"
    ports:
      - 8050:8050
      - 5023:5023
    expose:
      - 8050
      - 5023
```

The dockerfile for the scraper looks like this :

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /my_scraper

COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt  

COPY . .

EXPOSE 6800

CMD ["scrapyd", "--pidfile="]
```

And my splash settings are:

```
SPLASH_URL = 'http://splash:8050'
```

The rest of the settings in my scraper are as recommended by scrapy-splash docs.

However, when I run my scraper, it cant connect to Splash, and throws out this error:

```
2018-12-29 13:24:14 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-12-29 13:24:14 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-12-29 13:24:14 [sorg] INFO: Spider opened: wiki_scraper
2018-12-29 13:24:14 [sorg] INFO: Spider opened: wiki_scraper
2018-12-29 13:24:14 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-12-29 13:24:14 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.wikipedia.org/ via http://splash:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): 503 Service Unavailable
2018-12-29 13:24:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET https://www.wikipedia.org/ via http://splash:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
2018-12-29 13:24:14 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <403 https://www.wikipedia.org/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2018-12-29 13:24:14 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-12-29 13:24:14 [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Scraper close failure
```

I had a similar issue when building the scraper image, but that was solved with the expose command in the dockerfile. However, I use a ready made image for Splash, so I'm somewhat confused as to why I can't connect to it. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: When I use docker ip '192.168.0.14' in the SPLASH_URL setting, I get a different error, indicating (at least I think...) failure due to a timeout, rather than no service:

```
2018-12-29 14:36:28 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.wikipedia.org/ via http://192.168.0.14:8050/render.html> (failed 2 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
2018-12-29 14:36:30 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-12-29 14:37:23 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET https://www.wikipedia.org/ via http://192.168.0.14:8050/render.html> (failed 3 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting http://192.168.0.14:8050/render.html took longer than 55.0 seconds..
```

Comment: not sure if it isn't connecting or splash is returning a `503` response. It looks to me that you are able to connect, maybe bash into your `scraper` container and make manual requests to `http://splash:8050`, that will give you better confirmation if you can or cannot connect to the splash instance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm a bit new to docker, how would I try that manually? Wirth curl http://splash:8050?

Comment: this is not about docker, but splash, check what kind of requests splash accepts in the documentation.

Comment: I tried this "http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=http://example.com&timeout=10&wait=0.5", and it renders the page. However, this is a bit weird, since if instead 'localhost' i put "splash" it reports an unresolved host, and if I put my docker IP "192.168.0.14", it reports a timeout.

Comment: Forgot to specify, I used curl command.

Comment: @Ttheshirt Hi I'm also facing the similar issue. Were you able to solve this?